# Button skipping a scence after conversion from swiffy (iPad only)

Tags: html, ipad, flash, actionscript-2, google-swiffy

I am currently converting a few files from .swf to HTML 5 using Swiffy. Everything is working fine, except the next button is not stopping on the second scene and will go directly to the third scence from the first. This only happens on the iPad and the first time you tap the button. I believe the action script is right, it is simple action script 2:

```
on (release) {
   nextScene();
 }
```

I also used

```
on(release)
{
        gotoAndPlay("Scene 2", 1);
}
```

is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this kind of thing happen two or three times with Swiffy output - the solutions were different but more or less like this example:

Issue - I deleted scene 2 in a 3-scene FLA, then exported as swiffy. But instead of stopping at the end of scene 3 the animation looped back to the scene 1 and re-played forever.

Solution - opened a backup copy of the FLA file, deleted all but one frame of Scene 2 (i.e. left some trace of its existence) and re-exported. Then it worked, don't know why.